# How to resize tkinter Listbox to fit entire frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm having some trouble resizing a `Listbox` to fit the entire frame using tkinter grid method.

Code snippet:

```
Label(master, text = 'Total Profit :').grid(row = 5, sticky = W)
Label(master, text = 'Total Loss: ').grid(row = 7, sticky = W)
Label(master, text = 'Day Profit :').grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W)
Label(master, text = 'Day Loss :').grid(row = 7, column = 2, sticky = W)
Label(master, text = 'PORTFOLIO VALUE :').grid(row = 9, column = 0, sticky = W)
Label(master, text = 'CREATE ORDER (SYM, #): ').grid(row = 11, column = 0, sticky = W)


stepTwo = LabelFrame(master, text="ORDERS: ")
stepTwo.grid(rowspan=10, columnspan=10, sticky='nsew', 
             padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)



listbox = Listbox(stepTwo)
listbox.grid(rowspan = 10, columnspan = 10, sticky = 'nsew')
```

current gui:

[image: 1]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't match the code that you posted.

Comment: @BryanOakley True. I wanted to simplify it down as I didn't think portions of it necessary.

Comment: Hi Zachary, could you share a working solution to the problem. I am trying solve a similar problem but not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in using such huge row and column numbers. The grid inside `stepTwo` is independent from the grid in `master`.

In this case, it's simplest to use `pack`:

```
listbox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you insist on using `grid`, you need to follow the rule of thumb where you need to give at least one row and one column a non-zero weight so that grid knows how to allocate any extra space.

Example:

```
stepTwo.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
stepTwo.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'nsew')
```

Comment: This works! I was unaware that frames were separate from the window. Thanks for the help.